# how to extract last number sequence in an IP Address (using Linux)

Tags: linux, awk, string-manipulation

I want to extract the last digits of an IP Address based on the result of ifconfig command.

ifconfig often includes a whole heap of output so I'm not really sure how to get the digits that I want.

example:

```
root@my-pc:~/scripts# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:44:ca:43:d5:99  
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33685377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29363607 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3918498595 (3.6 GiB)  TX bytes:3888643193 (3.6 GiB)
```

I want to get the number 15 from the IP Address which is 192.168.1.15

Thanks very much :)

ps. Not really sure what tags to use so apologies in advance

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ip -o addr show dev "eth0" | awk '$3 == "inet" {print $4}' | sed -r 's!/.*!!; s!.*\.!!'
```

(Do not use `ifconfig` – use `ip addr`.)

Also, don't forget that an interface can have *multiple* IP addresses; not all addresses are `/24`'s; not all addresses start with `192.168.1.`; and not all addresses are IPv4. Such "quick" scripts will therefore break in many systems.

Comment: thanks! it works. It's a home network so I can control what IP range to use. :)